# jQuery Binding a change event to all class elements

Tags: jquery, class, event-binding

When binding a change event to class elements there is a need for an index to be applied to discover which class element produced the change event, for example `[0]` here.

```
var taskData = new Array;
$($( ".ctaskSelector" )[0]).bind('change', function () {
    var val = $(".ctaskSelector").val();
    var task_ID = taskData[val].task_ID;
    etc
});
```

One solution is to duplicate the code for each class index.  Is there a more sensible method of approaching this?

Comment: Use $(this) within the event handler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more sensible method to achieve what you need is to use the `this` keyword within the event handler, as the scope of the function is the element which raised the event:

```
var taskData = [];
// I presume you have some logic here to populate the taskData array...

$('.ctaskSelector').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var task_ID = taskData[val].task_ID;
    // etc
});
```

Also note that `bind()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should be using `on()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Rory for the solution and the advice concerning bind.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the element that raised the event, you can use `$(this)` or have an `event` attribute and use `event.target`.

```
$(".ctaskSelector").on('change', function(e){
   var element = $(this); 
   //or
   var element = $(e.target);
});
```

Comment: I am new to javascript and jQuery and this has given me a better understanding of $(this).   Thanks.

Comment: jQuery automatically binds the selected element to the function, probably trough `apply`. This is used to set what `this` refers to inside a function.